# first-child & first-of-type selector not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript toggle so T need to tried to collapse all sections on load by default - by inserting

```
ul.section-content{
  display:none;
}
```

and it is working. But when I tried to hide `first-child` or not `first-child` it is not working.

```css
.cscr .csec .section ul:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cscr">
  <ul class="csec">
    <li class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <div class="section-left">
          <h5>section01</h5>
          <p>hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-meta">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="section-content">
        <li class="course-item">
          <h1>lesson01</h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <div class="section-left">
          <h5>section02</h5>
          <p>hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-meta">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="section-content">
        <li class="course-item">
          <h1>lesson02</h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

second case:
and how to display only first and not others with help of not-first-child

[screenshot of what is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EtnS.jpg)

Comment: The code (as changed, after the answer pointing out your typo) works; the `ul`s are successfully hidden. If you want to negate, use the `:not()` selector, as in `:not(:first-child)`.

Comment: In your HTML `<ul class="section-content">` is **never** the first child element of its parent, so obviously you cannot use `:first-child` in any way to select that.

Comment: Then what should i ?

Comment: needed : ibb.co/iafyUz

Comment: Please use the image icon in the editor to include the screenshot, not a link to an image sharing site.

Answer (score 1):

> i need to display only lesson1 and what is the code for not displaying
>   only lesson1

Use `not` selector and select all the children other than the first one

```css
.cscr .csec li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cscr">
  <ul class="csec">
    <li class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <div class="section-left">
          <h5>section01</h5>
          <p>hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-meta">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="section-content">
        <li class="course-item">
          <h1>lesson01</h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <div class="section-left">
          <h5>section02</h5>
          <p>hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-meta">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="section-content">
        <li class="course-item">
          <h1>lesson02</h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it was just a typing mistake. but still it not working

Comment: Run the snippet and let me know what is not working?

Comment: I think this is why one should not answer typo questions; they could just be typos and now the answer is meaningless...

Comment: @TalhaHameed then tell me what is not working.Are you sure of the expected result?

Comment: i need to display only lesson1 
and what is the code for not displaying only lesson1

Comment: it is hiding everything. i just need to remain section1 visible (lesson1 - hidden) section2 + lesson2 both visible + section3 + lesson3 both visible and so on

Comment: @brk i hope you understood the problem

Comment: needed : https://ibb.co/iafyUz 
after your code : https://ibb.co/geVq9z